# Looping Through A Series of Pages (WebElement) Using Selenium/Python

Tags: javascript, python, element

I am trying to loop through a series of pages (javascript) from the following webpage:

http://nh.mypublicnotices.com/PublicNotice.asp?Page=SEARCHRESULTS

I found all of the elements that I need to loop through, but I am unable to click on it. What would be the best way to loop through these javascript elements:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

next_page=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//[@id="PublicNoticeContent"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[6]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a')

for i in next_page:
    link=i.get_attribute("href")
    Select(link)
    Select.click()
```

Comment: What is "Select"?  Since it's capitalized, I suspect it's a class name, rather than a function or object.  Please see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: my bad. Added clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat your materials on [Select](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html) and working with a class.

```
link=i.get_attribute("href")
Select(link)
```

This code has just grabbed what had better be a `SELECT` tag, but it certainly looks as if you've grabbed only an `href`.  You *tried* to create a `Select` object from that link ... but then, having created it, you failed to save it: you threw it away.

```
Select.click()
```

I'm not at all sure how you expect this to work: this invokes `click` as a direct call of a **class** method, but `Select` has no such method, so this will fail because teh attribute doesn't exist: an error message you failed to provide in your posting.

Start with this: once you work through your tutorial materials and learn to extract the proper SELECT tag from a URL `i` ... perhaps

```
select_tag = i.find_element_by_tag_name(“select”)).select_by_index(0)
clickable = Select(select_tag)
clickable.click()
```

You click on the *object* you created, not on the class.

Does that help get you going?  You still need to figure out how to code that first line in your application.